# Mysql. JSON. Why I get - Error Code: 1064

Tags: mysql, json

Simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE `LocalTest` (
  `mainJson` json NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Attempt to insert json value:

```
insert into `LocalTest` (mainJson) values ('{ "key": "value" }')
```

As result error:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Error Code: 3140. Invalid JSON text: "The document root must not be followed by ' at line 3
```

What wrong with this simplest script?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rWJJZoVupVsKNsw7vaJ6Eu/0

Comment: That error message means you're trying to execute an error message as a SQL query. Look at what it says after "near"

Comment: Yes, I just added ";" and it works. Thank you